# Receiving a StackOverflow error when clicking add button

Tags: java

So I'm working on a java project that will add, subtract, multiply, and divide 2 complex numbers. I have finished the GUI, works fine, but I'm getting a really odd error that I can't understand.

So I'm testing my add function first because it's easiest. Here is the code for my addButton action listener:

```
addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int r1, r2, imag1, imag2 = 0;

            String StrR1 = real1.getText();
            r1 = Integer.parseInt(StrR1);

            String StrR2 = real2.getText();
            r2 = Integer.parseInt(StrR2);

            String StrI1 = i1.getText();
            imag1 = Integer.parseInt(StrI1);

            String StrI2 = i2.getText();
            imag2 = Integer.parseInt(StrI2);

            ComplexNumber c1 = new ComplexNumber(r1, imag1);
            ComplexNumber c2 = new ComplexNumber(r2, imag2);

            ComplexNumber calcNum = c1.calcAdd(c2.getReal(), c2.geti());

            String str = calcNum.toString();
            outLabel.setText(str);
        }

    });
```

...and here is my entire ComplexNumbers Class so far:

```
public class ComplexNumber {
private int realNum = 0;
private int iNum = 0;

public ComplexNumber() {
    realNum = 0;
    iNum = 0;
}

public ComplexNumber(int r, int i) {
    realNum = r;
    iNum = i;
}

public void setReal(int r) {
    realNum = r;
}

public int getReal() {
    return realNum;
}

public void seti(int i) {
    iNum = i;
}

public int geti() {
    return iNum;
}

public ComplexNumber calcAdd(int r2, int i2) {

    int rCalc = realNum + r2;
    int iCalc = iNum + i2;

    return calcAdd(rCalc, iCalc);
}

public String toString() {      
    String Str = "";

    Str = (realNum + " + " + iNum + "i");

    return Str;
}
}
```

...so the issue is when I run my project and press my addButton, for some reason the code enters an infinite loop. Once I had the program print the calculated numbers, and they started in the thousands, continuing to increase until the code threw an overflow error.

I'm pretty sure it as something to do with the calcAdd function returning a complexNumber, and setting calcNum equal to that function. I've never tried something like that before and didn't think it would be much of an issue, but then this happened, and I can't think of anything else in my code that could have done it.

Any help?

EDIT: Looking at it again, I'm pretty sure I'm returning the wrong thing...but im not really sure what the right thing is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be getting a StackOverflow exception because you're calling the `calcAdd` recursively without a base case, in-fact you don't need to recursively call the method in the first place.

Your method should be:

```
public ComplexNumber calcAdd(int r2, int i2) {    
       int rCalc = realNum + r2;
       int iCalc = iNum + i2;
       return new ComplexNumber(rCalc, iCalc);
}
```